# error 0 in regular expression to exclude image with class

Tags: php, preg-match

I've tried to create a regular expression to search only images that not contain a specified class, but the server gives me **0 error** unexpected '/' separator.

```
$regex = '/<img((?!(.*?)class=['\"](.*?)nopopup(.*?)['\"](.*?)).*?>/';
```

Now my code is the next, I need that preg_match work only in images that not contain class nopopup

```
$regex      = '/<img.*?>/';

$createImageLink = function($imageTag)
{ 
preg_match('/src="([^"]*)"/i', $imageTag[0], $results);
$srcAttribute = $results[0];
$srcUrl = explode("=", $srcAttribute);
return '<a href=' . $srcUrl[1] . ' class="magnific_popup">'.$imageTag[0].'</a>';
};                                                     

if (isset($article->text))
{
$article->text = preg_replace_callback($regex, $createImageLink, $article->text);
$article->text .= '<script> jQuery( document ).ready(function() { jQuery(".magnific_popup").magnificPopup({ type: "image", enableEscapeKey:true }); });</script>';
}
if (isset($article->text))
{
$article->introtext = preg_replace_callback($regex, $createImageLink, $article->introtext);
$article->introtext .= '<script> jQuery( document ).ready(function() { jQuery(".magnific_popup").magnificPopup({ type: "image", enableEscapeKey:true }); });</script>';
}
break;
```

Where is the error?

Comment: What do you mean `0 error`?  And how do you run the regex and what is sample input?

Comment: You should probably ditch regexes in favor of [DOM parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php).

Comment: Question is too unclear for me, you get `0 error` or `unexpected '/' separator`? The `$regex` is invalid syntax and would never parse so you can't be getting either error. You also never use `$regex`. What is `$imageTag`? Why not use a parser?

Comment: Where'd the regex go with negative lookaheads?

Answer (score 0):

You must do like this :

```
$regex = '/<img(?!(.*?)class=['\"](.*?)nopopup(.*?)['\"](.*?)).*?>/';
```

in first line you have excess `(` symbol

https://regexr.com/4r4er

Comment: `$regex` is never used, but the first error really is `['\"]` because of encapsulation characters.

Comment: regex is used  next.
Can you give me a correct regular expression for exclude class?
how can I correct this `$regex = '/<img(?!(.*?)class=['\"](.*?)nopopup(.*?)['\"](.*?)).*?>/';`

Comment: its correct. try https://regexr.com/4r4er